# WS response parse my xml String '<' to '&lt'

Tags: java, xml, string, web-services

Thats my problem:

I have an xml located in a String variable. The String is correctly coded, but when I return its value in my WS response, it changes the '<' to '&lt'. I have tried to convert the String to XmlDocument without success.

I receive the xml code in a blob from DB, and I do the conversion like this:

```
SerializableBlob sb = (SerializableBlob) versionInfo.get(0);
byte[] data = sb.getBytes((long) 1, (int) sb.length());
myBean.setXml(new String(data));
```

In my WS:

```
@WebResult(name = "getDatosVersionReturn")
@WebMethod(operationName = "getDatosVersion")
public MyBean getXML(){

    Mybean myBean = myMethod.getMyBean();
    return myBean;
}
```

Can anybody help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

XML cant contains special characters. so If you use an appropriate class or library, they will do the escaping for you. There are only five:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

thats the reason your response contains those characters. at first deserilize your string then deserilize the result in to your class. if you post your code i can help you with details.